# Store PDF in the database but not as BLOB

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, hibernate-mapping

I want to be able to store a file location for a PDF file, instead of storing the actual file (since the files that I have are nearly 20 GB)
Then my Spring app could then open and display to the user
How could I do such thing by allowing the user to insert, view and delete these files ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `nginx` as a file server where you want to store your PDF file.

Keep the file location e.g. `http:someurl.com/pdf1` in the database

When you want user to view this pdf, give them this link from db

For delete you can run `rm fileLocation` from spring app and then delete the url from DB

Answer (score 0):

It is not a DB business. In the database you should save only reference for files only. Files should be stored in filesystem, and if you don't want to operate with files you can open stream on your Back End service and fetch data by stream, update it and close by some events in system. From the side of Front End you can use standart Form Data constuction or lot of libraries for operating with PDF, I recommend you to use Mozilla PDF.js library

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your responses. but I will upload the PDFs to the database and not use a file system.